# how to bind ngmodel to select option within an ngfor

Tags: angular

(I haven't been able to find a similar question to this on StackOverflow, if I missed anything please link me)
I have an ngfor loop looping over a list of records. Each record have multiple actions (edit, delete, etc.) in a select list. I want to be able to select an action that only applies to the record.

```
<tr *ngFor="let rec of records">

    <td><a href=""> {{rec.name}} </a></td>
    <td>{{rec.description}}</td>
    <td><a href=""> {{rec.date}} </a></td>
    <td>
        <select [(ngModel)]="selected" (change)="changeOption(rec);">
            <option selected disabled>Actions</option>
            <option value="editRec">Edit Record</option>
            <option value="deleteRec">Delete Record</option>
            ...more options
        </select>
    </td>
</tr>
```

changeOption right now just simply prints out this.selected, but whenever the ngModel is changed, the screen shows that select values for ALL records are changed (so they ALL show edit/delete/etc. whenever something is selected).

this is ok in the component file since i still know which record and which action are selected, but UI-wise it looks strange.
i think this is expected behavior since every select value is bound to this ngModel, but i'd like to know if it's possible to bind individually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's happening because you're using a primitive variable in your `[(ngModel)]` inside `*ngFor`.. so every *bind* will reference the same variable (in this case `selected`). To solve this, you can change ngModel to `rec.selected`:

```
<select [(ngModel)]="rec.selected" (change)="changeOption(rec)">...
```

[**PLUNKER**](http://plnkr.co/edit/2MKTibZWqBT93tqz78LG?p=info)

Comment: does this bind the model to the component's this.selected? if not what does it bind to? I tried this but console.log(this.selected) does not print the action selected.

Comment: I explained above why a single variable associated to multiple items won't work. Did you read it?

Comment: i did but i wasn't clear on what you meant. i think i got it now thank you

Comment: @QuanHuynh I just added a demo, check it :)